# How can I identify which component is causing a Flutterflow Page Error when loading?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Within Flutterflow

When moving between pages with a navigate action, with variables passed between screens, the destination screen breaks and shows a grey page.

Variables being passed are an amount double, an image path. a string, and an account document object reference.

The screen loads a drop down menu with a list of string values.

The Console Log does not show a lot of information about what went wrong, where the page transition is failing, or which variable is causing issues.

Output when the screen loads is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: [object Object] is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at a0.b8 (main.dart.js?1652057862:88960:18)
    at Object.aM (main.dart.js?1652057862:79323:26)
    at a0M.eX (main.dart.js?1652057862:96693:10)
    at e_k.$1 (main.dart.js?1652057862:177146:8)
    at buu.wJ (main.dart.js?1652057862:92138:33)
    at die.$0 (main.dart.js?1652057862:91234:11)
    at Object.av5 (main.dart.js?1652057862:5177:40)
    at bh.o0 (main.dart.js?1652057862:91147:3)
    at ceq.$0 (main.dart.js?1652057862:91006:16)
```

Some guidance would be great, or a way to add console.log() debugging into the flow of actions to break down what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not try yet - there is a debug mode which should give you more information on the exceptions. Instead of run select the dropdown next to it and select test.